# File upload not working server side

Tags: php

I am having trouble with file uploads. I have the below code which works perfectly locally. Now I have uploaded it to a server and the file is uploaded to the directory I have selected but the insert statement is not running.

```
<?php
require('../conn/include.php');
require('quick.php');

$project=$_POST['project'];
$title=$_POST['title'];
$keyword=$_POST['keyword'];

if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $errors=array();
    $allowed_ext=array('pdf','doc','docx','ppt','pptx','PDF');
    $filename=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $name=stripslashes($filename);
    $type=strtolower(end(explode('.',$filename)));
    $size=$_FILES['image']['size'];
    $file_tmp=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
if(in_array($type,$allowed_ext) ===false) {
    $errors[]= "<span class=\"notification n-error\">Extenstion Not Allowed</span>";
}
if($size > 52428800) {
    $errors[]= "<span class=\"notification n-error\">File must be less then 25mb</span>";
}if(file_exists('../../Downloads/b/'.$filename)) {
   $errors[]= "<span class=\"notification n-error\">File $filname Already Exists in directory</span>";

}if(empty($errors)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, '../../Downloads/b/'.$filename)) {
        $insert="Insert into `my`.publication(publ_title,publ_name,project,keyword)VALUE('$title','$name','$project','$keyword')";
        //echo $insert;
        $que=mysql_query($insert);
    echo "<span class=\"notification n-success\">File $filname Uploaded Sucessfully</span>";
    }
}else {
    foreach($errors as $error) {
        echo $error,'<br/>';    
    }
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I have changed Value to VALUES nothing happens moreover the file is uploaded to directory but mysql query is not running. Another suggestion Please

Comment: What is your **DB connection** method, `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*`?

Comment: If your connection variable, for example in your DB connection is `$con`, then use `$que=mysql_query($insert,con);` instead of `$que=mysql_query($insert);` or even just `mysql_query($insert,con);` or `if (!mysql_query($que,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); } echo "1 record added";` because you probably need to pass DB connection to query.

Comment: I need to know what's inside your included files for the DB connection.

Comment: I placed a sample DB connection and table selection in my answer below, as to how it should all work together.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I have selected but the insert statement is not running."*

This line contains `VALUE`

```
$insert="Insert into `my`.publication(publ_title,publ_name,project,keyword) 
VALUE ('$title','$name','$project','$keyword')";
  S--^
```

which should read as `VALUES` (in plural form)

```
$insert="Insert into `my`.publication(publ_title,publ_name,project,keyword) 
VALUES ('$title','$name','$project','$keyword')";
```

---

### EDIT

If your DB connection variable is `$con` for example, try:

```
$result = mysql_query($insert);
if($result)
    {
        echo "Successfully updated database";
    }
    else
    {
     die('Error: '.mysql_error($con));
    }
    mysql_close($con);
```

or try

```
$result = mysql_query($insert,$con);
if($result)
    {
        echo "Successfully updated database";
    }
    else
    {
     die('Error: '.mysql_error($con));
    }
    mysql_close($con);
```

and using an example connection and DB selection:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);
```

Comment: Thank i found this error Error: INSERT command denied to user 'blablabal' for table 'publi'

Comment: You're welcome. But what is the name of the table you wish to insert into? You presently have Insert into `my`.publication @user3314254